# Como criar esta procedure

Tags: sql, firebird, procedure

Tenho estas duas tabelas no banco

```
cadcha (Cadastro de chamadas)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
cadram (Cadastro de ramal)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todas as ligações realizadas em uma determinada empresa, serão salvas neste tabela `cadcha`. O campo ramal destino, é o ramal que atendeu ou realizou esta respectiva ligação. Também tenho uma segunda tabela, chamada `cadram`, onde são realizados os cadastro de ramal manualmente, e os relatórios do sistema são gerados a partir desta tabela cadram. Gostaria de implementar uma procedure que quando acionada, cadastrasse os ramais encontrados no campo **ramalorigem** da tabela **cadcha** na tabela **cadram** (Obviamente os ramais que ainda não tem cadastro). Exemplo:
Temos ali na tabela cadcha o **ramalorigem 4554**, porém na tabela cadram não temos este ramal ainda. Gostaria que a procedure realizasse isso.

O que consegui até o momento:

SELECT que retorna todos os ramais das ligações que ainda não foram cadastrados:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (RAMALDESTINO)
FROM CADCHA
WHERE RAMALDESTINO 
NOT IN 
(SELECT RAMCOD FROM CADRAM)
```

Escopo da procedure, que é a parte onde não consegui ir em frente:
Obs: Nas procedures do firebird é obrigatório passar um valor por parâmetro e retornar alguma coisa?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CADRAM_AUTOMATICO
(
teste VARCHAR(1)
) 
RETURNS 
(
    EXCEPTION "Procedure Acionada"
)
AS 
BEGIN
    FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT (RAMALDESTINO)
        FROM CADCHA
        WHERE RAMALDESTINO 
        NOT IN 
        (SELECT RAMCOD FROM CADRAM)
    DO  
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO CADCHA (RAMCOD, RAMDES) VALUES (RAMALDESTINO, 'RAMAL');
    END
END
```

Reforçando: preciso que a procedure cadastre os ramais na tabela cadram automaticamente pra mim, utilizando como base a tabela de ligações (cadcha) no campo ramaldestino.

Comment: Faça um script para polular atualmente a cadcha, e depois seria melhor uma ´TRIGGER AFTER INSERT´ vinculada a tabela cadcha.

Comment: O problema da trigger é que deixaria o sistema bem lento, pois alguns clientes realizam diversas ligações por minuto que são tarifadas em tempo real na tabela cadcha. Por isso optei pela procedure, porém percebi que a sintaxe dela é diferente da trigger, o que não acontece em alguns SBDBs como o SQL SERVER.

Comment: Entendi, mas ai não seria "automático", como você pensa em executar esse procedimento?

Comment: O automático que digo seria na parte de não ter que cadastrar os ramais manualmente um a um. A ideia é ter um botão "Atualizar ramais" que irá chamar está procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `procedure` para fazer o que deseja ficaria assim:

```
create procedure SP_CADRAM_AUTOMATICO
as
declare variable VRAMAL_DESTINO integer;
begin
  for
      select distinct
          (RAMALDESTINO)
      from
          CADCHA
      where
          RAMALDESTINO not in (select
                                   RAMCOD
                               from
                                   CADRAM)
      into
          VRAMAL_DESTINO
  do
  begin
    insert into CADRAM (
        RAMCOD,
        RAMDES)
    values (
        VRAMAL_DESTINO,
        'RAMAL');
  end
end
```